# Defer creation of controllers/services on app run angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing, angular-services, deferred-rendering

every time the route change, I check if is set a variable with the current logged user details, if this variable is not set, I simply redirect to the login page.

Now I'm trying to achieve some kind of "remember me" functionality, so every time the route changes, if the variable user doesn't exist instead of redirecting to the login page, I check the local storage for an "authtoken", if is set I call a check function passing the authtoken to the server, that returns the user and the app will works the same way as after the manual login (that returns the same user as the check function).

I'm pretty sure this is not the best way to do that.

If I reload the page, first thing I run the check function that sends the authtoken to the server and wait for a response, if the user exists that value is assigned to a variable in the rootscope.

I have different services that use the variable in the rootscope, for example

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .service('AdminService', function AdminService($rootScope, $http, StorageService) {
    var authtoken = StorageService.get('authtoken');
    var clientId = $rootScope.loggedUser.id;
```

and of course when the check function runs it waits for the response, but the service is being instantiated and $rootScope.loggedUser.id does not exists.

How can I tell the app to wait until the check function receive the response?

This is my code

```
....
}).run(function($rootScope, $location, AuthService, StorageService) {

var intended = $location.path();  

AuthService.check().success(function(data) {
    if(data.user) {
       $rootScope.loggedUser = data.user;
       $location.path(intended);
    } else $location.path('login');
});
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {

  if($rootScope.loggedUser) {
  ....
```

For example if the user bookmarks the page "myapp.com/#/admin/users", I don't want to redirect to the login, if I have in local storage the authtoken, but this causes the controller to be instantiated, that uses the service, that needs the $rootScope.loggedUser.id that is not yet populated.

And I want to run the function check only when the page (re)loads (not every time the user change route).

Comment: Take a look at `$routeProvider` and the `resolve` property of the route.

Comment: In that case it has to resolve each time the user visit that route? Because I want a one-time check when the user load the app, I don't need to check each time the user visit a route

Comment: Then you could use the `.run` method, but with authentication I suggest using resolve, because authentication may expire, etc... You don't need to make a server call every time, just examine the auth token for expiration

Comment: I don't know how to achieve that in the run function, the app doesn't wait until that server call returns the response, so all the other services that use the loggedUser variable in the routeScope, does not work and for the user is just a broken page, if he changes route everything works fine because now the loggedUser variable is populated. PS: The logic for session expiry is in the backend, if the app try to request an api to the server and his session has expired, it returns an error and I have a service that manage the errors, if is a session expired just redirects to the login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise to re-examine your design if you need a service call to check your auth token. Auth tokens typically have expiration time stored in them, so you could just check whether you are within the expiration period without calling the server. You are not compromising security, since auth tokens are signed by the server, and validated when you make server calls to do anything useful. So, under normal circumstances, no separate `check` call is needed.

But, if you insist, this use case is best handled with the `resolve` property of the route. This means, however, that every route that cares about the user's logged-in state would have to have a resolve property defined. This does not mean that you have to call the service on each route change.

Instead of using `$rootScope.loggedUser` to store the user, have it be cached by the `AuthService` and injected via the `resolve` parameter.

So, you could do the following:

```
$routeProvider
   .when("some/secure/route", {
          controller: "SecureCtrl",
          resolve: {
             user: AuthService.checkUser
          }
        });
```

And in your AuthService:

```
...
checkUser: function(){
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  if (cachedUser){
     deferred.resolve(cachedUser);
  } else {

     AuthService.check().success(
        function(data){
           // cachedUseris defined at AuthService's scope
           cachedUser = data.user;
           deferred.resolve(data.user);
        });
  }

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Then, in your controllers:

```
.controller("SecureCtrl", function(user){
   $scope.userId = user.id;
}
```

Comment: I really like this approach, thanks, but I'm not following the logic. Never used provider....
I need to inject a provider in the .config(
so I created an AuthServiceProvider, that returns a check function that uses $http and StorageService, but I'm in a loop, also AuthServiceProvider requires the $httpProvider and the StorageServiceProvider... it looks like I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something... why do you need to create an AuthServiceProvider?

Comment: I told you I was doing something wrong....I was injecting AuthService in the wrong spot, now it works great, thanks! The app is an admin panel so each route is protected, now I have to put resolve on each route, it would be great if I could do this in one place, for every route. Thanks again!